# Python extract unknown string from dataframe column

Tags: python-3.x, pandas

New to python - using v3. I have a dataframe column that looks like

```
object
{"id":"http://Demo/1.7","definition":{"name":{"en-US":"Time Training New"}},"objectType":"Activity"}
{"id":"http://Demo/1.7","definition":{"name":{"en-US":"Time Influx"}},"objectType":"Activity"}
{"id":"http://Demo/1.7","definition":{"name":{"en-US":"Social"}},"objectType":"Activity"}
{"id":"http://Demo/2.18","definition":{"name":{"en-US":"Personal"}},"objectType":"Activity"}
```

I need to extract the activity, which starts in a variable place and is of variable length. I do not know what the activities are. All the questions I've found are to extract a specific string or pattern, not an unknown one. If I use the code below

```
dataExtract['activity'] = dataExtract['object'].str.find('en-US":"')
```

Will give me the start index and this

```
dataExtract['activity'] = dataExtract['object'].str.rfind('"}}')
```

Will give me the end index. So I have tried combining these

```
dataExtract['activity'] = dataExtract['object'].str[dataExtract['object'].str.find('en-US":"'):dataExtract['object'].str.rfind('"}}')]
```

But that just generates "NaN", which is clearly wrong. What syntax should I use, or is there a better way to do it?  Thanks

Comment: How do you convert your dictionaries/objects to a pandas dataframe? Please provide a small code snippet for better understanding and demostration. Does "definition" always contain one dictionary/object only?

Comment: The data is in a csv, so
import pandas as pd
dataExtract = pd.read_csv('training.csv')

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I suggest convert values to nested dictionaries and then extract by nested keys:

```
#if necessary
#import ast
#dataExtract['object'] = dataExtract['object'].apply(ast.literal_eval)

dataExtract['activity'] = dataExtract['object'].apply(lambda x: x['definition']['name']['en-US'])

print (dataExtract)
                                              object           activity
0  {'id': 'http://Demo/1.7', 'definition': {'name...  Time Training New
1  {'id': 'http://Demo/1.7', 'definition': {'name...        Time Influx
2  {'id': 'http://Demo/1.7', 'definition': {'name...             Social
3  {'id': 'http://Demo/2.18', 'definition': {'nam...           Personal
```

**Details**:

```
print (dataExtract['object'].apply(lambda x: x['definition']))
0    {'name': {'en-US': 'Time Training New'}}
1          {'name': {'en-US': 'Time Influx'}}
2               {'name': {'en-US': 'Social'}}
3             {'name': {'en-US': 'Personal'}}
Name: object, dtype: object

print (dataExtract['object'].apply(lambda x: x['definition']['name']))
0    {'en-US': 'Time Training New'}
1          {'en-US': 'Time Influx'}
2               {'en-US': 'Social'}
3             {'en-US': 'Personal'}
Name: object, dtype: object
```